# Biblatex: philosophy-verbose

Tags: biblatex

I want to use both philosophy-verbose and bibcitefn option for smallcaps-author. I prove that this match is possible only if I use philosophy-classic style, but [the guide](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-philosophy/biblatex-philosophy.pdf) (p. 15) tells that it is possible also for philosophy-verbose style.

So, this is my bib code.

```
\usepackage[style=italian]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,scauthors=bibcitefn,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Then, this is an example and I remind you that the following upper case in this example should be small caps.

So, document:

> This is the body of my page. Follows the name of one author I want to cite: he is Trump, the former potus and he said that if he were still the potus today, Russia wouldn't invade Ukraine (1).
>
> ---
>
> 1 D. TRUMP, *My words*, Oxford University Press, Oxford 2022, p. 5.

And the code of this document should be:

```
This is the body of my page. Follows the name of one author I want to cite: he is \citeauthor{trump2022}, the former potus and he said that if he were still the potus today, Russia wouldn't invade Ukraine \footcite[5]{trump2022}.
```

Bibliography:

> an entry

> another entry

> D. TRUMP, *My words*, Oxford University Press, Oxford 2022.
>
> another entry

Can someone helps me?

Follows a working example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=italian]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,autocite=footnote,scauthors=bibcitefn,classical=true,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,editionformat=romansc,volnumformat=strings,volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyvt,loccittracker=context,idemtracker=constrict,latinemph=true,indexing=cite,uniquework=true,minnames=2,uniquetitle=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\AtBeginBibliography{\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{\iftoggle{bbx:scauthorsbib}{\usebibmacro{bbx:scswitch}}{}\nameparts{#1}\ifgiveninits{\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}{\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\printlist{publisher}\iflistundef{location}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}\printlist{location}\setunit*{~}\usebibmacro{date}\newunit}
\addbibresource{quoted.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{layout}\author{Francesco Contini}\date{May 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My title}
This is the body of my page. Follows the name of one author I want to cite: he is \citeauthor{trump2022}, the former potus and he said that if he were still the potus today, Russia wouldn't invade Ukraine \footcite[5]{trump2022}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way the `biblatex` implementation of full citations often mixes citation and bibliography settings. This means that they sometimes fall through the cracks when options are offered that distinguish citation and bibliography output.

The following redefinition tries to make citations in the footnote also respond to `bibcitefn`, but even if this works as you hoped in all edge cases, you may still want to contact the `biblatex-philosophy` developer if the documentation suggests that `bibcitefn` should do what you expected

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style=italian]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-verbose, scauthors=bibcitefn]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifwantsc}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:scauthorscite}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\iftoggle{cbx:scauthorscitefn}
       {\iffootnote}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro{cite:full:noshorthand}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\ifwantsc
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{scdefault}}%
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}}%
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citeauthor{sigfridsson}
ipsum \footcite[380]{sigfridsson}.
dolor \footcite{worman}
ipsum \footcite[381]{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde, «Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments», Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19, 4 (1998), pp. 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P, p. 380.]